# Youtube in iframe on facebook - Z-index issue

Tags: facebook, iframe, youtube

I've embedded a Youtube video in my facebook app, but when I scroll down, the youtube video floats above the facebookmenu-bar. Which looks kind of awful, see screenshot.

At first glance, the problem only shows in Chrome and Internet Explorer, not in Firefox.
It seems to be a Z-index issue. I've tried adding &wmode=Opaque to my youtube-url, but no luck.

Did someone else have this problem? If so, what did you do to solve it?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is with the embedded youtube frame.  You need to add this to the  query string of the url for it to work right:

wmode=transparent

You get something like this:

www.youtube.com/embed/xxxxxxxxx?wmode=transparent&rel=0

That will fix the z index issue of embedded youtube videos sitting on top of all other windows and modals.

Comment: I don't have any relevant css yet, but this is my php code:

echo "<object style='height: 317px; width: 520px'><param name='movie' value='http://www.youtube.com/v/".$youtubecode."?version=3&feature=player_detailpage&amp;wmode=transparent'><param name='allowFullScreen' value='true'><param name='allowScriptAccess' value='always'><embed src='http://www.youtube.com/v/".$youtubecode."?version=3&feature=player_detailpage&amp;wmode=transparent' type='application/x-shockwave-flash' allowfullscreen='true' allowScriptAccess='always' width='520' height='317'></object>";

Comment: Even though I cant read the links due to display limitations within comments (it would be helpful if I could), i'm not 100% sure on this, but with this object notation, it looks like since you have movie value = link, and another entity (a param?) with name = 'allowFullScreen', have you tried the equivalent of making another param (or whatever is going on in the code that I cant see) set to name = 'wmode' and value='transparent'?

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I've found the solution. It's indeed with the parameter ?wmode=transparent or opaque, but this doesn't work with an object. Converting the object to an iframe did the trick. I give you +1 for helping, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var frames = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe");

    for (var i = 0; i < frames.length; i++) {
         frames[i].src += "?wmode=opaque";
    }
});
```

This code works for me.

Answer (score -1):

I think this is a new facebook bug as it is happening to all video embeds suddenly. Not something posters should have to fix or tweak.

Comment: It only occurs when youtube video's are embedded as objects. When you embed the video as an iframe and add ?wmode=transparent to the embedded url, it's fixed.